# Convert SQL query to LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The below is my SQL query and want to be in LINQ. Can anybody help for this?

```
SELECT EmpId,Team,_Year FROM Plan
where EmpId in
(
    select EmpId from master where 2150 in (immediatesupervisor,manager)
)
```

Comment: What database is this? I don't know any database where that code would work (particularly the `where 2150 in (immediatesupervisor,manager)` bit)

Comment: forget LINQ, try and write correct SQL first.

Comment: @Dean it is probably SQL Server since the question is tagged with 'linq-to-sql'. If _master_ has a column named _immediatesupervisor_ and a column named _manager_ that SQL query should work. Any specific reason it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use join operation like this

```
YourDbEntities db = new YourDbEntities();

var query = from c in db.Plan
            join d in db.master on c.EmpId equals d.EmpId
            where d.ImmediateSupervisor == 2150 || d.Manager == 2150

            select new{
              c.EmpId,
              c.Team,
              c._Year
            };
```

Comment: All numerical identifiers are not allowed in c#. I think '2150' is a literal value rather than a member. I'm assuming _immediatesupervisor_ and _manager_ are table members...

Comment: thank you... I almost left about that 2150. I've correct my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var q =
from p in dc.Plan
where (
  from m in dc.Master
  where m.ImmediateSupervisor == 2150
     || m.Manager == 2150
  select m.EmpId
  ).Contains(p.EmpId)
select new { p.EmpId, p.Team, p._Year };
```

A great resource for commonly used linq syntax is Damien Guard's Linq-to-SQL 'cheat sheet'. It is a one-pager where you can quickly look up things like this. See http://damieng.com/blog/2009/08/12/linq-to-sql-cheat-sheet